# beautiful soup works sometimes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here I have a very simple scraper for the name of an item on llbean

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def mainTest():
    url = "http://www.llbean.com/llb/shop/43281?feat=506697-GN2&page=women-s-l-l-bean-boots-10-shearling-lined&attrValue_0=Brown/Brown&productId=732934"
    page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), "html5lib")
    name = soup.find('h1', attrs={'itemprop':'name'}).text
    print name
    print str(soup)[:100]

mainTest()
```

This scraper works usually. It usually prints what I want:

```
                                Women's Bean Boots® by L.L.Bean, 10" Shearling-Lined

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en"><head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta c
```

But sometimes it prints:

```
None
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

This is a pretty hard error to repeat and I am sorry for that. I believe that the issue may lie in llbean sometimes loading faster than my scraper and sometime my scraper scraping first.

Does anyone know of a way to slow my scraper down maybe?

It may also be a different problem altogether.

Comment: Did you check the http status code? Are you sure the site isn't occasionally returning an error?

Comment: Have you considered using scrapy? If you are gonna be scraping llbean you could use a crawlspider

Comment: Executed it like hundred times in a loop - always getting the "Women's Bean Boots...".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @kyleheitman I'll take a look

Comment: I will look into that @FatalError

Comment: @alecxe I am running on a VM, maybe the VM gets extraordinarily slow sometimes whereas your machine is better. If you are getting consistency maybe when i push it to a server it will be more consistent.

Comment: See the updated answer!

Answer (score 0):

To me below code is working - care **encoding**. I tried more than 10 times with success.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def mainTest():
    url = "http://www.llbean.com/llb/shop/43281?feat=506697-GN2&page=women-s-l-l-bean-boots-10-shearling-lined&attrValue_0=Brown/Brown&productId=732934"
    page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
    page=page.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html5lib")
    name = soup.find('h1', attrs={'itemprop':'name'}).text.encode('utf-8')
    print name
    print unicode(soup)[:100]

mainTest()
```

It prints-

```
                                Women's Bean Boots┬« by L.L.Bean, 10" Shearling-Lined

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta content="IE=edge
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue while scraping from youtube for some embedded urls for a list of movies for my django webapp..
I don't know may be my internet connection was slow or something, my soup finds the element sometimes and sometimes it just returns None,
making another request when i got None type while scraping that element solved my problem....

My workaround...

```
while(1):
        try:
            try to scrape your element using BeautifulSoup
        except AttributeError:
            print('retrying....')
        else:
            break
```

if your loop breaks then you got the element, if you got None type from soup, it will go to except and retry again (i.e, iterates the while loop again), then if soup finds the element in second request fine, if you are running into infinite loop, it is obvious that you are accessing a element which is not there,
you can also limit the while loop like 10 retry requests max...